# Print to a file in java

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to print a String called 'source' to a java file called Paper.java using PrintWriter, but it never gets printed to the file. The openToWrite method in the WriteToFile class has a try-catch that makes outfile a PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter outfile = WriteToFile.openToWrite("Paper.java");
outfile.println(source);
System.out.println(source);
outfile.close();
```

This is my code for the openToWrite method:

```
public static PrintWriter openToWrite(String fileName)
{
    PrintWriter outFile = null;
    try
    {
        outFile = new PrintWriter(fileString);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File could not be created");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    return outFile; 
}
```

The file that I'm writing to, Paper.java, is under the same java project.

Sorry for such a basic level question! I'm just starting to learn java. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: works for me if you just do `outfile = new PrintWriter("Paper.java");` So it must be your `WriteToFile.openToWrite()`

Comment: You will need to provide the code for `openToWrite` just to be sure.  Also make sure that where you think the file is been written to is the same place the file is actually been written to

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got two different variable names -- fileName vs fileString